# MKMapView click on pin causes weird frame changes

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkpinannotationview, autolayout

I created not custom, simple pin annotations on `MKMapView` and when I click on it, I'm getting following for my MapView:

[image]

It happens only on iOS8.

I figured out that without constraints for mapView - it works fine.
Constraints are simple - just to be fullscreen when rotating device.
here are they:

```
[self.mapView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.mapView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:0]];
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.mapView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:0]];
```

`MapView` is added to `ViewController.view` and I'm not getting any warnings about conflicting constraints so on.

Why it happens?
And what is most unfair why clicking on `MapView` annotation causes it...

Comment: Did you get anywhere on this issue. I've been seeing this too and would love to be able to resolve it

Comment: it was long time ago, I don't remember details but posted solution as an answer

Comment: Outstanding! thanks so much, today you have saved a man from insanity  :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't go to details but for some reasons mapView after clicking on annotation had a center in left/top corner of parent view,

so setting center anchor did the trick:

> ```
> [self.mapView.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.centerXAnchor].active = true;
> [self.mapView.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.centerYAnchor].active = true;
> ```

I guess this is because I specified height/width constraints but nothing about positioning, so defining top/left constraints, 
also could help